# Show only exact values of data point on axes with matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show only exact values (x, y) on axes or coordinates of data point by matplotlib. My work below that

```
def plot_sample_individual(id = None):
  if id is None:
    id = random.randint(0, len(ca_the))
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(5, 5))
  ax.plot(week[:7], ca_the[id, :],'--ro')
  ax.set_title('ID cá thể '+ str(ID[id, 0]))
  ax.set_ylabel('Sản lượng trứng trung bình tuần')
  ax.set_xlabel('Tuần')
```

and result of code is:

[image]

How to show only 3 values on axes y and 5 values in axes x ?

Comment: What do you mean by `exact values`? Which *values* do you want to shown on the x and y axis'?

Comment: I want to drop the values which isn't point's coordinates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the x and y data to [set the Axes ticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = [24,25,26,27,28]
y = [7,4,5,4,4]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_yticks(y)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

---

[Ticks and tick labels](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/axes_api.html#ticks-and-tick-labels)

Comment: but I had used random id to choose sample so x array is not unique

Comment: @TungNg - You didn't provide any data in your [mre] so my made my own -the data points in my example match the data points in your plot.  If you are looking for something a little more specific, you should update your [mre] - including how the function is called. Even though you may be generating `id` in the function, you can still use the values as I have shown.